# zurb foundation error messages displayed by default?

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

I am working with foundation.abide.js in a rails 4 application, the basic code setup included below.  No matter what I try or what I google for I can not seem to determine why the default form always shows the red error messages.  Any ideas on what I am missing?

[image]

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <h2>Abide</h2>
    <h4 class="subheader">Abide is an HTML5 form validation library that supports the native API by using patterns and required attributes.</h4>

    <form class="custom" data-abide>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Fieldset</legend>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-12 columns">
            <label for="password">Password <small>required</small></label>
            <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="LittleW0men." name="password" required>
            <small class="error" data-error-message>Passwords must be at least 8 characters with 1 capital letter, 1 number, and one special character.</small>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-12 columns">
            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
            <input type="tel" id="phone" placeholder="1 234-567-8910">
            <small class="error" data-error-message>Please enter a properly formatted telephone number.</small>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-4 columns">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="foundation@zurb.com">
            <small class="error">Valid email required.</small>
          </div>
          <div class="large-4 columns">
            <label for="url">URL <small>required</small></label>
            <input type="url" id="url" placeholder="http://zurb.com" required>
            <small class="error" data-error-message>Valid URL required.</small>
          </div>
          <div class="large-4 columns">
            <div class="row collapse">
              <label for="customDropdown1">Hardest to find in grocery <small>required</small></label>
              <select id="customDropdown1" class="medium" required>
                <option value="">Select grocery item</option>
                <option value="first">Green Chilies</option>
                <option value="second">Raisins</option>
                <option value="third">Panko bread crumbs</option>
                <option value="fourth">Assistance</option>
              </select>
              <small class="error" data-error-message>Broke.</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-12 columns">
            <hr>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-6 columns">
            <label for="radio1"><input name="radio1" type="radio" id="radio1" required><span class="custom radio"></span> Radio Button 1</label>
            <label for="radio1"><input name="radio1" type="radio" id="radio1" required><span class="custom radio"></span> Radio Button 2</label>
            <label for="radio1"><input name="radio1" type="radio" id="radio1" required><span class="custom radio"></span> Radio Button 3</label>
          </div>
          <div class="large-6 columns">
            <label for="checkbox1"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" style="display: none;" required><span class="custom checkbox"></span> Label for Checkbox</label>
            <label for="checkbox2"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" CHECKED style="display: none;" required><span class="custom checkbox checked"></span> Label for Checkbox</label>
            <label for="checkbox3"><input type="checkbox" CHECKED id="checkbox3" style="display: none;" required><span class="custom checkbox checked"></span> Label for Checkbox</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-12 columns">
            <hr>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-12 columns">
            <label for="remarks">Closing Remarks</label>
            <textarea id="remarks" name="remarks" placeholder="Leave your remarks here."></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-12 columns">
            <button type="submit" class="medium button green">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </fieldset>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it data-abide in your <form opening tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to find the problem with only the HTML snippet (which looks ok, so the problem has to be somewhere else).

Did you make sure that:

- You included ALL the CSS from the zurb foundation framework and DID NOT accidentally overwrite some of the CSS properties (check with the DIV inspector that the 'error' class is indeed hidden by default)
- Make sure that you do not have a JS snippet that is trying to send/verify the form upon page load

If you want a more detailed analysis, publish the whole thing somewhere so that we can see the complete setup that you have there (HTML + CSS + JS)

Comment: I did not have it setup correctly, you were correct. Thank you.